# Ktor Unit Testing with JWT and Firebase Auth

Tags: firebase-authentication, jwt, ktor

I have Ktor Jwt authentication setup with Firebase Auth and working except in my unit testing. Getting `TRACE io.ktor.auth.jwt - Failed to get JWK: Failed to get key with kid null`

I'm wondering if `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createCustomToken(UUID.randomUUID().toString())` is not working.

Here is one of my unit tests:

```
test("when register for game and userId is not found then NotFound is returned") {
    coEvery { userRepositoryMock.getUser(any()) } returns null
    withServer {
        val req = handleRequest(HttpMethod.Get, "/api/game/1/2") {
            addJwtHeader()
        }
        req.response.status() shouldBe HttpStatusCode.NotFound
        req.response.content shouldBe "Could not find user."
    }
}

private fun TestApplicationRequest.addJwtHeader() = addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer ${getToken()}")

private fun getToken() = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createCustomToken(UUID.randomUUID().toString())

private fun withServer(block: TestApplicationEngine.() -> Unit) {
    withTestApplication({ module() }, block)
}
```

Comment: Could you please share your dependencies?